# How to create a widget(customized widget) using flutter and use that widget in react(web) application and flutter mobile application

Tags: javascript, html, flutter

I have a requirement to create a widget (I will be creating multiple widgets and passing values between them) and use it across different applications. I have created it as a package and am able to use it in a Flutter application. However, I am confused about how to use it in a React web application. I have some basic knowledge that we can create a JavaScript file, deploy it, and use it as a script. To use the js file, we need to include the script tag in our HTML file.